# .pwd: Invalid argument and Illegal Instruction errors

Tags: software-installation

I followed this [guide](http://yaui.me/using-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-time-capsule/) today and now I'm kind of stuck.

Almost every time when I try to run a command now, I get an `Illegal Instruction` error.

E.g.

```
$ sudo umount -l /media/Backup 
Illegal instruction
xx@localhost:~ $ sudo service netatalk stop
Illegal instruction
xx@localhost:~ $ sudo service avahi-daemon stop
Illegal instruction
```

When I try to change my password (what I was planning on doing), I get:

```
$ passwd
Changing password for xxxx.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: 
.pwd: Invalid argument
BAD PASSWORD: 
New password:
```

And on the boot I get a error saying, that the `Apply Kernel Variables` could not be started:

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service
● systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-03-31 22:51:40 UTC; 30min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysctl.service(8)
           man:sysctl.d(5)
  Process: 105 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 105 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
Illegal instruction
```

Does anyone have an idea, what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You followed an obsolete tutorial and installed services which were already installed and used `init.d` on a `systemd` OS. I suggest you restore from your backup.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, fair enough, I know I did something wrong. But, any advices how to fix it? I uninstalled the self-compiled package but the error stays.

Comment: Trying to undo the many things is almost impossible. I use `netatalk` (the version from repository) but not for TimeCapsule. `avahi` is already installed, but would be installed by `netatalk`. There is probably nothing wrong with installing `hfsplus`, although this doesn't support journalling like a native Mac.